# show next/previous items of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using next/previous buttons to show the corresponding items of an array.  I am experiencing two issues...

1) when the page loads, I need to click previous or next two times before anything will happen

2)  Let's say I'm at record ID 10 for example.  If I press 'next' 5 times to get to record ID 15, then press 'previous', instead of taking me to 14, it will take me to ID 16.  If I then hit previous again (and subsequent times), the ID will then decrease as normal.  Same thing with previous: If I start at ID 15 and hit previous down to 10, clicking 'next' will take me to ID 9 instead of 11.  Then, subsequent clicks of 'next' will increase the ID as normal.

Hopefully this will help explain what I mean...
https://jsfiddle.net/mjcs351L/

This uses a super hero API.  You will need your own to test the code but it's free and doesn't even ask you to sign up: https://www.superheroapi.com/

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
var apiKey = "YOUR API";
var charID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 731) + 1);
var website = "https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/" + apiKey + "/" + charID;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', website, true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
  getinfo();

  function getinfo() {
    document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = result.biography["full-name"];
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result.name;
    document.getElementById('egos').innerHTML = result.biography["alter-egos"];
    document.getElementById('charID').innerHTML = result.id;
    document.getElementById('birth').innerHTML = result.biography["place-of-birth"];
    document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = result.appearance.height;
    document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML = result.appearance.weight;
    document.getElementById('gender').innerHTML = result.appearance.gender;
    document.getElementById('race').innerHTML = result.appearance.race;
    document.getElementById('eye').innerHTML = result.appearance["eye-color"];
    document.getElementById('hair').innerHTML = result.appearance["hair-color"];
    document.getElementById('occupation').innerHTML = result.work.occupation;
    document.getElementById('connections').innerHTML = result.connections["group-affiliation"];
    document.getElementById('relatives').innerHTML = result.connections.relatives;
    document.getElementById("pic").src = result.image.url;
    document.getElementById("pic").style.height = 300;
    document.getElementById("pic").style.width = 300;
  }



  function nextItem() {
    var test = charID + 1;
    var website = "https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/" + apiKey + "/" + test;
    req.open('GET', website, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      charID = test;
      getinfo();
    });
    req.send(null);
  }

  function prevItem() {
    var test = charID - 1;
    var website = "https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/" + apiKey + "/" + test;
    req.open('GET', website, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      charID = test;
      getinfo();
    });
    req.send(null);
  }


  document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    prevItem();
  });

  document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    nextItem();
  });

  event.preventDefault();
});
req.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and follow DRY (don't repeat yourself), it makes it easier to debug code. I've tweaked the code a bit to re-use components.

```
var apiKey = "YOUR API";
var charID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 731) + 1);

function fetchData(id) {
  id = id || charID;
  var website = "https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/" + apiKey + "/" + id;
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', website, true);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  req.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    getinfo(result);
  });
  req.send(null);
}

fetchData()

function getinfo(result) {
  document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = result.biography["full-name"];
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result.name;
  document.getElementById('egos').innerHTML = result.biography["alter-egos"];
  document.getElementById('charID').innerHTML = result.id;
  document.getElementById('birth').innerHTML = result.biography["place-of-birth"];
  document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = result.appearance.height;
  document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML = result.appearance.weight;
  document.getElementById('gender').innerHTML = result.appearance.gender;
  document.getElementById('race').innerHTML = result.appearance.race;
  document.getElementById('eye').innerHTML = result.appearance["eye-color"];
  document.getElementById('hair').innerHTML = result.appearance["hair-color"];
  document.getElementById('occupation').innerHTML = result.work.occupation;
  document.getElementById('connections').innerHTML = result.connections["group-affiliation"];
  document.getElementById('relatives').innerHTML = result.connections.relatives;
  document.getElementById("pic").src = result.image.url;
  document.getElementById("pic").style.height = 300;
  document.getElementById("pic").style.width = 300;
}


function nextItem(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  fetchData(++charID)
}

function prevItem(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  fetchData(--charID)
}

document.getElementById('prev_button').addEventListener('click', prevItem);

document.getElementById('next_button').addEventListener('click', nextItem);
```

Comment: Thank you much!  So much cleaner.  I knew I wasn't doing it the most efficient way! 
I am using your code above but now the previous | next buttons don't work.

Comment: No errors.  The record just does not change when pressing those buttons now.

Comment: Could you check the networks tab in the console and see if the requests for the `next` and `previous` records are going through?

Comment: Networks tab in the console?  I'm sorry, I guess I'm a noob.  I'm using Notepad++ to edit my JS file.

Comment: You are testing it by opening the html file on the browser, right? Open the page on the browser and then follow this guide(https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/#details) to monitor your `api requests`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience.  I think I am where you want me to be now.  The only error I see in console is "hero3.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at hero3.js:52"

Comment: It does not look like the requests for next and previous are going through

Comment: The error mentioned above says that the `elements` where you are trying to attach the actions are not found. Basically the elements with id `prev_button` and `next_button` is not found.

Comment: Strange.  I didn't touch anything in my HTML file.  I have this...                       
 <div>
    <span id="prev_button">Previous</span>
    <span id="next_button">Next!</span>
</div>

Comment: Move the script tag after the body, the error is occurring because the initialisation is happening before the elements are rendered.

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe you figured that out without even looking at what I'm working with.  Everything is working perfectly now.  I can't thank you enough.  Do you have a Paypal ID so I can buy you a cup of coffee?